# I need to count data that the user inputs in python

Tags: python, count, raw-input

I'm very new to python and I'm having trouble with a specific question. I need to count a character or word that the user will input in python. So essentially I have to count whatever the user inputs into 'Please enter a string and please enter a substring'.I added the "h = h.lower" because we have to ensure the string is al lower case. What I have so far is:

```
def highlight(): 
        h = h.lower()
        print (raw_input("Please enter a string: "))
        print (raw_input("Please enter a substring: "))
        print("There were",  "occurrences of" +str(raw_input))
```

Comment: lower() is used on the strings themselves. You need to assign your inputs to variables, i.e. h = raw_input('Please enter a string: ')

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, if you are talking about counting a particular character in a string then use,

str.count(sub[, start[, end]])

Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

```
word = 'elephant' 
word.count('e') 
#Gives you 2
```

Comment: Im trying to count a specific character. I get that character from whatever someone inputs in python. So i run the code in python and type in a sentence after "Please enter a string". Lets say they type in 'elephant', I want to find all the e's in that word.

Comment: >>> word = 'elephant'                                            
>>> word.count('e')    
>>> 2